# JSON.Parse + Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Делаю Ajax запрос который возвращает мне такие строки

Не могу за парсить такую строку:

`{"status":"ok","data":{"yok":[{"players_online":52750,"server":"China"}]}}`

В консоле посмотрел response так после yok идет число 0 но если парсить так

```
response.data.yok.0.players_online;
```

То ничего не получится выведет ошибку о наличие чсила

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yok это массив а 0 это индекс элмента. `response.data.yok[0].players_online`

Answer (score 4):

```js
var str = {"status":"ok","data":{"yok":[{"players_online":52750,"server":"China"}]}};

alert(str.data.yok[0].players_online);
```